# What would happen if someone opened a door that is opened with a key of the keymaker from the other side?

Tags: the-matrix, paradox

In the Matrix Reloaded, Persephone is opening a door in the restaurant using a key from the keymaker, now leading to the Merovingian's chateau 500 miles away instead of the other part of the restaurant. But what would happen if someone from the restaurant's other part wanted to enter the door in the other direction while being open to the chateau? For an observer from the other side, is the door open or closed? If it's already open, what would it look like if they tried to enter the part where Persephone and the redpills come from?

Comment: A locked door, presumably

Comment: @Valorum So in case they have the key and can't open the door, what would the eventual explanation be?

Comment: The Matrix isn't a perfect system. If you watch the Animatrix short *Beyond*, you can see what happens if a glitch occurs. Agents roll in, turn the thing into a parking lot and roll back out again.